# Как сделать кастомную подсветку теста в js?

Tags: javascript

Библиотеки типа codemirror подсвечивают текст для определённых языков, но там нет возможности указать свои кастомные правила подсветки, хочу подсвечивать незакрытые скобки в математических выражениях.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [Prism.JS](https://prismjs.com/).

Свежее решение насущных проблем. В базовой версии всего 2кб кода. Работает без единой зависимости. Поддержка [275 языков](https://prismjs.com/#supported-languages).

Расширяется [плагинами](https://prismjs.com/#plugins).

[Плагин соответствия скобок](https://prismjs.com/plugins/match-braces/) также имеется.

```js
const plain = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
code.innerHTML = plain.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
.brace-hover { transform: scale(2); 
               transition: all 0.5s; 
               position:relative; 
               display: inline-block; }

* { font-size: 0.85rem; }
```

```html
<!-- CSS PRISM -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/themes/prism.min.css"/>

<!-- CSS MATCH BRACES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/plugins/match-braces/prism-match-braces.min.css"/>

<!-- JS PRISM -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/prism.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS MATCH BRACES -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.25.0/plugins/match-braces/prism-match-braces.min.js"></script>

<!-- CODE BLOCK -->
<pre>
<code id="code" 
      contenteditable="true" 
      class="lang-html match-braces rainbow-braces">

</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: этот редактор не поддерживает ввод и редактирование текста?

Comment: @Artyom Это не редактор, это подсветка кода, но я могу посоветовать и редактор.
[CodeJar](https://medv.io/codejar/) и [Blize](https://mcanam.github.io/iblize/)

Comment: @DiD спасибо. Полезный ответ для меня! Даже плагин для SVG есть, а это большая редкость.

Comment: @DiD blize, кажется, то что надо, спасибо

Comment: @Artyom если из редакторов нужно решение помощнее, то в вашем распоряжении [monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) от Microsoft. Накодили они конечно знатный редактор. Правда я его не осилил внедрить куда-либо...

Comment: @DiD Blize меня устраивает всем кроме того что он не подсвечивает круглые скобки и незакрытые скобки, и нельзя как то это задать. Хотя в документации есть ссылка на prism, но плагин prism для скобок тут не работает. Нужно создавать свой языковой файл?

Comment: @Artyom не, там проще всё, лучше тогда попробуйте CodeJar. Эти два редактора похожи очень. В документации `const highlight = (editor: HTMLElement) => {
  const code = editor.textContent;
  editor.innerHTML = code;
}
let jar = CodeJar(editor, highlight);`
Вместо этого вставьте Prism: `const highlight = (editor: HTMLElement) => {
  const code = Prism.highlight(editor.textContent, Prism.languages.javascript, 'javascript');
  editor.innerHTML = code;
}
let jar = CodeJar(editor, highlight);` И так вы замените подсветку на Prism.

Comment: @Artyom Если не получится, я вам выложу свой редактор... но он у меня с блекджеком и девочками. его код пока не опубликован нигде и соответственно, по нему документации нету, только я один вместо документации, но там все просто... Если что, обращайтесь, будет время, расскажу принципы построения редакторов... может, напишете свой... там не сложно...

Comment: @DiD установил через npm в проект с vue, пишет CodeJar is not defined

Comment: Ну там нет кода регистрации плагина Vue. Можно просто добавить на страницу `import {CodeJar} from 'codejar';
import Prism from 'prismjs';` как и всегда и будет работать.

Comment: @DiD заработало, но на половину. Скачал CodeJar и prismjs с проставленными галочками на плагине для подсветки скобок и подсветкой js, но скобки он не подсвечивает

Comment: @Artyom Я исправил немного код в ответе. Посмотрите. Грузится все с CDN и работает.